# Comparison of a string variable and a string is throwing error in shell script

Tags: string, shell, sh

I am working on a small shell script for backing up the sever logs to amazone. We have multiple servers running on production. So I wrote a script that dynamically detect the server and do the back up. But I am facing an issue while comparing two strings. I will give the code snippet below I wrote and the error.

```
test.sh    

host="$(hostname)"
if [ "$host" == "server1-myapp.com" ]; then
   function_1 $host
elif [ "$host" == "server2-myapp.com" ]; then
   function_2 $host
elif [ "$host" == "server3-myapp.com" ]; then
   function_3 $host
fi

function_1 () {
   echo "host name is $1"
}

function_2 () {
   echo "host name is $1"
}

function_3 () {
   echo "host name is $1"
}
```

But when running test.sh as **sh test.sh** I am getting the following **error**.

```
 test.sh: 2: [: server1-myapp.com: unexpected operator
 test.sh: 4: [: server1-myapp.com: unexpected operator
 test.sh: 6: [: server1-myapp.com: unexpected operator
```

I tried different ways to match two strings as one is a variable and other is a inline string, it is not matching strings properly can any one please help me, I am kind off stuck.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Looks like `case` will suit your script better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare string in shell with the `[ ]` operator it's with `=` and not `==`. This will works:

```
if [ "$host" = "server1-myapp.com" ]; then
```